# Typescript remote debugging

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a compiled typescript (JS) deployed to a web server. Source map is not published but I have them on my local box. Is there a way to use my local map file to debug production website either with browser or with Visual Studio? Running the site from local machine is not an option. Publishing source map to the server is also not a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Chrome developer tools you can add the source maps.
When you open the source file, right click on the content and click "Add source maps".
Versions need to match offcourse or you will get some very weird stuff when stepping through the code.

See screenshot

[image: Sourcemaps]

Comment: I had Chrome v37 while the latest version is v38. v37 doesn't have this feature. :|